# return data from $.post call undefined on first try

Tags: jquery, ajax

I need to store the data returned from a jquery $.post call in a variable called `result`.
the code below works except on the first click `result` comes back as undefined...
on the second click it returns the data from the php file as expected.
Thanks.

```
$('a').on('click',function(){
  var cv = $(this).data('cv');
  var url= '_php/myphp.php';
  $.post(url,{contentVar:cv},function(data)
  {
    result = data
    return result;    
    });
    alert(result);
});
```

Comment: You can just replace the word `data` in the callback to `result` rather than assigning it after the fact.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an AJAX call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Comment: you can't return data from a asynchronous call like that... there is probably a 1000 question with the same topic... the solution is to use  a callback function to process the value returned by ajax as mentioned each of those questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the `.done()` method, you are waiting for the AJAX call to get a successful response before alerting the result.

```
$('a').on('click',function(){
  var cv = $(this).data('cv');
  var url= '_php/myphp.php';
  $.post(url,{contentVar:cv},function(data) {
    result = data;
    return result;    
  }).done(function() {
      alert(result);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use result as global variable.

Global variable will let you use the variable outside the scope:

```
var result;
$(function(){
    $('a').on('click',function(){
      var cv = $(this).data('cv');
        var url= '/echo/json/';
      $.post(url,{contentVar:cv},function(data)
      {
        result = data;
        //you don't need any return, its callback function 
      }).done(function(){
          alert(result);
      });

    });
});
```

You can find more information on:
http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/global_variable

Comment: Its doesnt matter if its async or not. the only thing the async will affect its when you calling the variable. if you call it after the assemble you will get the right value.

Comment: i think u missed something dude. it will.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like,

```
var result=null;// initially initialize this variable
$('a').on('click',function(e){
   e.preventDefault();// use this line to prevent its default behaviour
   var cv = $(this).data('cv');
   var url= '_php/myphp.php';
   $.post(url,{contentVar:cv},function(data)
   {
      result = data;
      alert(result);// first alert
      return result;    
   });
   alert(result);// its global now, check this too
});
```

If this not fixes then use [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax) with `async:false` option. Call your `Ajax code` synchronously so that the `result variable` initialized and you get the `result` after your `Ajax call`.

Comment: You should place the alert inside the post callback before the return